# onPostExecute not called after completion AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

For some reason my `onPostExecute()` is not called after my `AsyncTask` finishes.

My class decleration:

`public class setWallpaperForeground extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>`

My onPostExecute():

`protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)`

Everything works fine, my `doInBackground()` completes successfully and returns a Boolean but then it just finishes.

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Did you create your AsyncTask on the UI thread? Also add an @Override annotaiton on your onPostExecute() method to make sure you declared it correctly.

Comment: I didn't have the @Override there. Looking at the example (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) neither do they. Why must I have one over onPostExecute() but none of the others?

Comment: It seems to work on the Emulator but not on the phone. When the background processes finish no Toast notification appears. The layout does look like it re-loads for some unknown reason. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to have @Override, but it's a way to ensure you properly overrode the method.

Comment: I had made the mistake of using  OnPostExecute instead of 'onPostExecute'.Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I had the Asynctask created outside of the UI thread. Thanks for the solve!

Comment: I get an error when overriding the onPostExecute... anyone know why?

Answer (score 56):

Did you start the task with `execute()` method? The `onPostExecute` wouldn't run if you just invoke the `doInBackground`.

Comment: @Konstantin  Than how to call onpostexecute()?

Comment: @developer onPostExecute is called automatically for you, after doInBackground returns. Unless a cancel was called on the async task.

Comment: @KonstantinBurov yeah now its woking .Thank you :)

Answer (score 31):

### Found/Made another nasty mistake:

If your params of `onPostExecute(Param param)` don't match the one you defined with `extends AsyncTask<...,...,Param>` and you didn't use the `@Override` annotation, it will never be executed and you don't get a warning from Eclipse.

Note to myself:
Just always use the `@Override` annotation and Eclipse will help you.

### Another easy way to avoid all named mistakes:

in Eclipse: `Right-click in code > Source > Override/Implement Methods`

Comment: I just solved my colleague's problem here - he was using boolean instead of Boolean!

Comment: Wow, thank you. I had no idea prior to this post that when I extend AsyncTask I have to explicitly mark the type of the returned value. I just had `extends AsyncTask` with no types

Answer (score 5):

After having the same problem and none of these answers helped me, I found out that my UI thread was blocked (I used a [`CountDownLatch.await()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await())) and therefore the `onPostExecute()` method that is supposed to be called by the UI thread was never called.

Answer (score 3):

Made another nasty mistake that can result in this same error. When defining the AsyncTask and calling it, I was not calling `execute` but was calling `doInBackground`

```
new AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>() {
    ....
}.doInBackground("parameter");
```

rather than

```
new AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>() {
    ....
}.execute("parameter");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. None of the above solutions worked for me. Then i figured out the problem maybe it helps someone else .

In UI thread i call the following codes:

```
public class XActivity ...{
    onCreate(){
        ....

        new SaveDrawingAsync(this).execute();

        while(true)
        {
            if(MandalaActivity.saveOperationInProgress){
                continue;
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
            break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

My AsyncTask class definition :

```
public class SaveAsync extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
        saveThem(); // long running operation
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        XActivity.saveOperationInProgress = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
       XActivity.saveOperationInProgress = true;
    }

}
```

in the above code onPostExecute is not called. It is because of an infinite loop after asynctask execution .
asynctask and inifinite loop both waits eachother to finish. Thus the code stucks!

The solution is changing the design!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behaviour, and the cause was that I have been posting a lot of messages as a progress inside doInBackground with following code:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     // .. some UI updates
   }
});
```

this must have overloaded main thrad message queue, and caused long delay before onPostExecute would get called. The solution was to post only once every second.

Comment: I counted number of seconds (using System.currentTimeMillis()) between each time I posted to handler

Answer (score 0):

For me it was user error. I was ending the AsyncTask by invoking cancel(true) on it and not reading the documentation closely enough to know that onPostExecute is not called in this case, onCancelled is.