# How to take Data from Intent in Android

Tags: java, android

*Hello everyone, I need to take parameter id = 55 from this picture, does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!!*

`System.out.println(voznja.toString());`

[image]

When I try to log in console, I always get the error that object reference is null.

Comment: Could you post code snippet and logcat in here?

Comment: @Daniel.Wang yes i can

Comment: okay, Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `extras.getString("voznja")` it returns null because `voznja` is not a `String`. Its class is `Voznja` so you have to write your code like this:

```
Voznja voznja = (Voznja) extras.getSerializableExtra("voznja");
```

Now you can get the id by this line:

```
voznja.get("id");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994815/debugger-doesnt-enter-into-the-onpostexecute-method-in-android Please take a look a this question, i need help here. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I don't think I can help here. You can search for some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606505/onpostexecute-not-called-after-completion-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

I think that the id you are trying to read is in an object.
I would first suggest using :
`voznja = extras.getSerializableExtra("voznja")`
Then, I would use this to extract the id from the object : 
`voznja.get(0);`
let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks, but that is not answer :(

Comment: That is the answer, please edit your answer here so i can accept it. THANKS!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65994815/debugger-doesnt-enter-into-the-onpostexecute-method-in-android Please look at this question, i need help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your class implements Parcelable use:

```
Voznja voznja = extras.getParcelableExtra("voznja");
```

And if it implements Serializable use:

```
Voznja voznja = extras.getSerializableExtra("voznja");
```

And then you could get the id from your object.